# PHP freaking out (connection dropped, connection abandoned) in IIS 7.5

Tags: php, windows, iis, dll

I'm having some problems with IIS and PHP (plus a com dll). The COM dll crashes fairly often, but *I think* the problems are not due to that (i have disabled rapid fail protection), because the dll always crashed, while the problems started about three weeks ago when we reached about 15.000 users/day.

What happens is that suddenly all .php files stop responding and the server is only able to serve static .htm files, which indicates there is a problem with php (php-cgi.exe).

This almost always happen during peak hours ( 3-4-5PM ) when google analytics shows 180-220 "online users". When this happens (the freaking out of PHP i mean) I can see in the server's task manager that instead of normally 10-12 php-cgi.exe processes they spike up to 30 or 40 php-cgi.exe processes ( of ~30 MB RAM each) , which I guess happens because php-cgi.exe stops handling the requests. The server has a total of 8GB RAM.

The error logs include both **connection_abandoned_by_regqueue** and **connection_dropped** and if I don't manually restart IIS or the defaultapppool, the errors will turn most of the times into **defaultapppool not available 503**

One issue is that in the event viewer I never get a message from WAS that the defaultapppool was disabled so that I could attach a task ( of restarting the pool) to it and in the IIS management console I never see the defaultapppool as disabled despite the fact that it shows as disabled in the logs.

I have been playing around with timeouts but but never seem to get something right.

My current theories are:

1) PHP freaks out with many users ( Windows, IIS ) and can't handle it

2) the crashing of the .dll causes troubles when many users are online

3) php+iis compatibility is not that good in high volumes, though I don't believe 15k/day are too many users. I should note though, that most requests take anywhere from 50-300 milliseconds to complete.

php version is 5.3.19 installed via WebPI, windows version is windows 2008 R2 64bit.

For some weird reason, notepad++ shows the query strings of the abandoned/disabled queries, in httperr log in a non-copyable hex form ( the querystrings are UTF8 - greek ) while in the normal logs, the query strings are both visible and copyable. screenshot provided below.

I'm also providing a second screenshot with current settings

HTTPERR logfile...errors start with connection dropped and then a bit later with connection abandoned
http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/3796/9nkv.jpg

in the second screenshot are my current settings: 1) enabled php extensions, 2) defaultapppool ( the pool the website runs on ) settings 3) php fastcgi settings and 4) php runtime limits.
http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/2531/o6d1.jpg

my last setting tweaking today was to auto-recycle the defaultapppool every 3 minutes and to disable dynamic content compression. Will see how that will go .

If anyone has any hints/ideas on the solution I would appreciate that alot!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible Rapid Fail protection is kicking in for the App pool due to the errors?

Comment: @uSlackr i don't know, i doubt it, as you can see in the screenshot i have explicitly disabled it.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that

Comment: DDOS/Brute Force attack perhaps? Are you sure those 180-220 online users are legit users and not bots?

Comment: @user2464424: Well, he said they show up in ga, so at least the agent used is a js-capable browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the limit of 32 processes for php-cgi.exe in the FASTCGI feature of iis manager. Upping that to 64 solved the problem temporarily. The reason I got up to 32 processed is that the webservice is CPU heavy. Finally by moving to a dedicated server with more cores and more ram was the final solution.

Answer (score 2):

Could I suggest going to 5.3.27 (the final release of 5.3) and see if that fixes it? There are too many crash bugs that were fixed between 20 and 27 to count. Might be the obvious solution but worth a shot.

Comment: maybe i should try running php as ISAPI module? or would that cause the whole IIS to crash when the .dll crashes instead of having just php-cgi.exe crashing now with fastcgi?

Comment: Maybe. I'm not familiar enough with IIS to say. I think that would make PHP run inside IIS like mod_php does for Linux. Another option would be to try Apache for Windows instead. Am curious to see if 5.3.27 works first tho.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid running php FastCGI in iis. Chances are you'll get better performance with php caching instead of fcgi.
2. This sounds frighteningly similar to a Slow Loris attack.
3. You may need to review timeout settings, and make sure fcgi is releasing the connections correctly. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.pooling.php
4. Could also be caused by a faulty dll.
5. Also worth running a full mem-check, as I've seen faulty ram cause this too.

Comment: maybe i should try running php as ISAPI module? or would that cause the whole IIS to crash when the .dll crashes instead of having just php-cgi.exe crashing now with fastcgi?